# print out first letter of each item in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that asks for a word input until '' is entered. Then the program will print out all of the words joined in a sentence. Then take the first letter of each word to make an acrostic. I am using python. Example shown below. Thank you in advance. This is due really soon. :)

- What I have coded:

```
sentence = []

acrostic = []

word = -1

while word:

     sentence.append(word)

      acrostic.append(sentence[0].upper())
print(sentence)
print("-- {}".format(acrostic))
```

- What I want the code to do:

```
Word: A

Word: cross

Word: tick

Word: is

Word: very

Word: evil

Word: 

A cross tick is very evil

-- ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input:

- in a loop, ask the user a word, if it nothing just stop
- if it's a word, save it in `sentence` and it's first letter in `acrostic` (`word[0]` not `sentence[0]`)

For output:

- for the sentence join the words with a space : `" ".join(sentence)`
- for the acrostic, join the letters with nothing : `"".join(acrostic)`

```
sentence = []
acrostic = []
while True:
    word = input('Please enter a word, or enter to stop : ')
    if not word:
        break
    sentence.append(word)
    acrostic.append(word[0].upper())

print(" ".join(sentence))
print("-- {}".format("".join(acrostic)))
```

Gives

```
Please enter a word, or " to stop : A
Please enter a word, or " to stop : cross
Please enter a word, or " to stop : tick
Please enter a word, or " to stop : is
Please enter a word, or " to stop : very
Please enter a word, or " to stop : evil
Please enter a word, or " to stop : 
A cross tick is very evil
-- ACTIVE
```

Comment: I think OP means `''` as an empty string.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck on that for ages :)

Comment: @coder1234 to stop, do you want to just type enter and so empty string, or type `" ` ?

Comment: It was just when the user just typed enter, but that was easily changeable.

Comment: @coder1234 Top ! You may now think about accepting an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

#### python 3.8 or later

```py
sentence = []
acrostic = []
while user_input := input('word: '):
    sentence.append(user_input)
    acrostic.append(user_input[0].upper())

print(' '.join(sentence))
print(f"-- {''.join(acrostic)}")
```

output:

```
word: A
word: cross
word: tick
word: is
word: very
word: evil
word: 
A cross tick is very evil
-- ACTIVE
```

#### python 3.6 and 3.7

```py
sentence = []
acrostic = []
while True:
    user_input = input('word: ')
    if not user_input:
        break
    sentence.append(user_input)
    acrostic.append(user_input[0].upper())

print(' '.join(sentence))
print(f"-- {''.join(acrostic)}")
```

#### python 3.5 or earlier

```py
sentence = []
acrostic = []
while True:
    user_input = input('word: ')
    if not user_input:
        break
    sentence.append(user_input)
    acrostic.append(user_input[0].upper())

print(' '.join(sentence))
print('-- {}'.format(''.join(acrostic)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
sentence = []
acrostic = []
word = -1

while word != "":
    word = input("Word: ")

    if word:
        sentence.append(word)
        acrostic.append(word[0].upper())

print(" ".join(sentence))
print("-- {}".format("".join(acrostic)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Goal: To extract first letter of each word untill '' is entered.

```
acrostic = ""
sentence = ""
while(True):
    word = input("enter a word= ")
    if(word!=''):
        acrostic+=word[0].upper()
        sentence+=word+" " 
    else:
        break
print(sentence)
print(acrostic)
```

With your sample input;

```
enter a word= A
enter a word= cross
enter a word= tick
enter a word= is
enter a word= very
enter a word= evil
enter a word=
```

output

```
A cross tick is very evil
ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

While everybody has you covered for basic loops, this is a nice example to use the [`iter(callable, sentinel)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) pattern:

```
def initial():
    return input('Word: ')[:1]

print('-- ' + ''.join(iter(initial, '')))
```

Will produce:

```
Word: A
Word: cross
Word: tick
Word: is
Word: very
Word: evil
Word: 
-- Active
```